# How to generate array of int [] with iota?

Tags: d

I need to generate array of `int []`. How I can do it. Method `iota` return uint, but I need to get `int`s:

```
int [] myarr2 = (iota(0, 10).array);
```

`app.d(11): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (array(iota(0, 10))) of type uint[] to int[]`

Comment: Your code works for me. dmd 2.072.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] myarr2 = iota!(int)(0, 10).array;
```